# Can an "enum" be used for flags in COM?

Tags: com, enums, idl, midl

In the IDL for a COM object I do the following:

```
enum TxMyFlags
{
,    flagOption = 1,
,    flagOtherOption = 2,
,    flagMoreOption = 4,
,    flagAnotherFlag = 8,
,    flagExtra = 128
// etc.
};
```

and have functions that can take the sum (or bitwise-OR, same thing) of flags, e.g. (in IDL)

```
HRESULT _stdcall a_method([in] enum TxMyFlags);
```

with an example of intended usage being:

```
a_method( flagExtra | flagMoreOption );
```

It seems to work but is this actually permitted, or is it possible that the RPC transport or whatever would reject values of an enum parameter that are not exactly in the enum definition?

Comment: Sure, enums are well supported in COM.  Nothing better than having an extra level of indirection to map a type from one to another in interop.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm asking specifically about whether a COM method's parameter of `enum` type can have an integer value given to it that is not one of the members of the enum (e.g. `132` in my example)

Comment: Sure, an *int* maps to an enum.  Ought to be obvious from the IDL.  You keep trying to find non-existing problems, no idea what the point might be.  Enlighten us.

Comment: I don't see how it is "obvious from the IDL". Also, the MIDL documentation says that the max value of an enum without `v1_enum` tag is 65535, so it cannot be true that `int` maps to the enum.

Comment: Regarding "non-existing problems", just because something seems to work now, does not mean that it is guaranteed to work. (For example, I used a `long` as `[optional]` parameter for years with no problem, before discovering it was actually not supported, and a particular language binding had trouble with it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your client and server are in process (and there is no real mashaling happening, no RPC involved), you will not see any problem as the enum, however you define it, will be treated as its int/long/whatever integral type equivalent in size.

So it's the out-of-process (or cross apartment marshaling) case that maybe an issue. In this case, as stated in the doc here: [enum attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366818.aspx) (and in your comments):

> Objects of type enum are int types, and their size is
>   system-dependent. By default, objects of enum types are treated as
>   16-bit objects of type unsigned short when transmitted over a network.
>   Values outside the range 0 - 32,767 cause the run-time exception
>   RPC_X_ENUM_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE. To transmit objects as 32-bit entities,
>   apply the [v1_enum] attribute to the enum typedef.

So you basically have two options to use enums in idl: 1) use `enum` without `typedef` and 2) use `enum` with `typedef` and add the `v1_enum` attribute. In the first case, you can just declare the type in the method as you want on the wire, in the second, you will have to use that type (hence the v1_enum attribute):

```
enum MY_ENUM
{
    MY_ENUM_FIRST = 1,
    MY_ENUM_SECOND = 2,
};

typedef [v1_enum] enum
{
    MY_ENUM_TYPE_FIRST = 1,
    MY_ENUM_TYPE_SECOND = 2
} MY_ENUM_TYPE;

[object, uuid(15A7560E-901B-44D2-B841-58620B1A76C5)]
interface IMyInterface : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT MyMethod1(int myParam);
    HRESULT MyMethod2(MY_ENUM_TYPE myParam);
};
```

used like this:

```
IMyInterface *p = ...;
p->MyMethod1(MY_ENUM_FIRST | MY_ENUM_SECOND);
p->MyMethod2(MY_ENUM_TYPE::MY_ENUM_TYPE_FIRST | MY_ENUM_TYPE::MY_ENUM_TYPE_SECOND);
```

If you declare a method like this:

```
 HRESULT MyMethod1(enum MY_ENUM myParam);
```

Then you will use a 16-bit enum (and you can't add v1_enum on a not-typedef'd enum), so that's not good (unless you're ok with the 0-32767 limit).

Note I also declared this to ease typedef enum as flags conversion in the second line:

```
MY_ENUM_TYPE operator | (MY_ENUM_TYPE l, MY_ENUM_TYPE r) { return (MY_ENUM_TYPE)((int)l | (int)r); }
```

Well. The typedef way seems a bit overkill to me, but it has the advantage of being typed. If you scan Microsof's own .IDL files in the Windows SDK, you'll see they basically use both...

Comment: Thanks, good answer. The `operator|` definition is a good idea, it would save a bunch of casting when using scoped enums. (Since the compiler I use started on C++11 support, it imports IDL `enum MY_ENUM` to C++ `enum class MY_ENUM`).